# Powershell & Get-ADUser - Split OU getting the 3rd, 4th and 5th elements from the end

Tags: powershell, split, active-directory

Running the following in Powershell I get the result below.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DistinguishedName | select DistinguishedName | Select-Object -Property @{label='Result';expression={$_.DistinguishedName}}
```

**Result**

```
CN=User Full Name 1,OU=AMS,OU=DS,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=User Full Name 2,OU=TECHM,OU=DS,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=User Full Name 3,OU=Agencies,OU=HK,OU=Developers,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=User Full Name 4,OU=Agencies,OU=CH,OU=Developers,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=User Full Name 5,OU=Agencies,OU=US,OU=Developers,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=User Full Name 6,OU=Market,OU=PP,OU=Developers,DC=domain,DC=local
CN=User Full Name 7,OU=Market,OU=HK,OU=Developers,DC=domain,DC=local
```

**This is my OU in Active Directory**

```
DS
 AMS
 TECHM

Developers
 CH
  Agencies
  Market
 HK
  Agencies
  Market
```

I need a way to adapt this query (doing a split or whatever) so I am able to obtain the third item (comma separated) - most important - from the end and 4th and 5th. This is the output I'd like to get:

```
OU          Where     Type
--------------------------------
DS          AMS       N/A
DS          TECHM     N/A
Developers  CH        Agencies
Developers  CH        Market
Developers  HK        Agencies
Developers  HK        Market
```

I found some examples to split strings but nothing to accomplish what I am trying here.

Any ideas?!

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be more helpful if you showed us what you tried that didnt _accomplish what I am trying here_. That way we can so you how to make it work.

Comment: Why down vote? Everything is pretty clear and explained. I am down voting your comment.

Comment: Please don't _assume_ it was me. Voting is anonymous. I am trying to help you is all I was doing. You suggested you tried something. I thought you might have liked to know where you went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the values you're wanting to extract, I'd start with CanonicalName, rather than DistinguishedName:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName |
 select -ExpandProperty  CanonicalName |
 ForEach-Object {
  $Parts = $_.split('/')

   $Object = 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
     OU = $Parts[1]
     Where = $Parts[2]
     Type = 'N/A'
     }

  if ($Parts.count -ge 5)
    { $Object.Type = $Parts[3] }

  $Object
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. No results on OU, Where and Type is giving N/A always of course.

Comment: Had canonicalname split on the wrong character ('\' instead of '/').  Fixed.

Comment: Great. It worked. Now, using the same thing, how can I also get other parameters (e.g. DisplayName, SamAccountName, EmailAddress)? The result would be OU, Where, Type, DisplayName, SAMAccountName, EmailAddress

Answer (score 0):

You are not interested in ",DC=domain,DC=local", so you might as well remove them by either -replace ",DC=domain,DC=local","" or by using substring method of string.

You really did not need that last select-object, nor specifying DistinguishedName, as by default you would get that with get-aduser

For example

```
$users = (get-aduser -filter *).distinguishedname -replace ",DC=domain,DC=local",""
```

Then, you split the results with "," to a temporary array variable and get the ones you like, starting from the last one using array index [-1]

```
$users | foreach {$where = $type = $OU = ""}{
     $temp=@($_ -split ",")
     if ($temp.count -eq 1) {

        $OU = $temp[0].substring(3) # substring to remove the first 3 chars, that is OU= or CN=

     } elseif ($temp.count -eq 2) {

       $where = $temp[1].substring(3)
       $OU = $temp[0].substring(3)

     } else {

       $type = $temp[-1].substring(3)
       $where = $temp[-2].substring(3)
       $ou = $temp[-3].substring(3)

     }
# Finally create a custom obhect out of these
[PSCustomObject]@{
  Type=$Type
  Where=$where
  OU=$OU
 }
}
```

I am typing this on top of my head, you should test but I guess you get the idea..

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will test that and let you know the results but my main goal would be to do all this in a query and not using functions, etc. Not sure if that is even possible though.

Comment: I am getting the following error message

Unable to find type [PSustomObject]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.
At script.ps1:44 char:1
+ [PSustomObject]@{
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (PSustomObject:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: Umm, I think I had a typo [PSustomObject] instead of [PSCustomObject] and you copy/pasted it. Fixing in code