# Powershell & Get-ADUser - Part 2 - Putting A & B Together

Tags: powershell, split, active-directory

I posted a question some time ago and it was answered to accomplish what I needed - [Powershell & Get-ADUser - Split OU getting the 3rd, 4th and 5th elements from the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772157/powershell-get-aduser-split-ou-getting-the-3rd-4th-and-5th-elements-from-th)

**ANSWER GIVEN**

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName |
 select -ExpandProperty  CanonicalName |
 ForEach-Object {
  $Parts = $_.split('/')

   $Object = 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
     OU = $Parts[1]
     Where = $Parts[2]
     Type = 'N/A'
     }

  if ($Parts.count -ge 5)
    { $Object.Type = $Parts[3] }

  $Object
}
```

Now I need to add some other fields (Name, SAM Account, Email) and do a check on the email*. This is my second query.

**Powershell Query**

```
$Headers= @{Label="OU Path";Expression={$_.CanonicalName}},
@{Label="Distinguished Name";Expression={$_.DistinguishedName}},
@{Label="Name";Expression={$_.DisplayName}},
@{Label="SAM Account";Expression={$_.SAMAccountName}},
@{Label="E-mail";Expression={$_.EmailAddress}},

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties
CanonicalName,DistinguishedName,DisplayName,
SamAccountName,EmailAddress | Select $Headers
```

How can I combine what it was provided in the answer of my previous question and this query to have the following output?

Also I need to check the email and if @company.com then "EType" = YES.

**EXPECTED END RESULT**

```
OU          Where     Type      Name     SAM      Email               *EType
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DS          AMS       N/A       Name1    brname1  name1@company.com   YES
DS          TECHM     N/A       Name2    xsname2  name2@company.com   YES
Developers  CH        Agencies  Name3    agname3  name3@gmail.com     NO
Developers  CH        Market    Name4    chname4  name4@company.com   YES
Developers  HK        Agencies  Name5    agname5  name5@other.com     NO
Developers  HK        Market    Name6    hkname6  name6@company.com   YES
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like if your @Headers where correct:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName,DistinguishedName,DisplayName,SamAccountName,EmailAddress | Select-Object @{Label="OU Path";Expression={$_.CanonicalName.Split("/")[1]}},
@{Label="Where";Expression={$_.CanonicalName.Split("/")[2]}},
@{Label="Type";Expression={if ($_.CanonicalName.Split("/").Count -ge 5) { $_.CanonicalName.Split("/")[3] } else { 'N/A' }}},
@{Label="Distinguished Name";Expression={$_.DistinguishedName}},
@{Label="Name";Expression={$_.DisplayName}},
@{Label="SAM Account";Expression={$_.SAMAccountName}},
@{Label="E-mail";Expression={$_.EmailAddress}},
@{Label="EType";Expression={ if($_.EmailAddress.IndexOf("@company.com") -gt -1) { 'YES' } else { 'NO' } }} | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thanks but when I run it I only get the Distinguished Name and the SAM Account

Comment: Well, canonicalname is not ADUser property, I thought you had that part sorted out.

Comment: You missed the -Properties after the Get-ADUser -Filter. When I added it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you edit my post and add the properties there or post them as comment so I can fix it. I originally thought that it would not matter since the filter is *.